# Django dumpdata Unable to serialize database: Could not decode to UTF-8 column

Tags: python, django, sqlite, utf-8

I have a sqlite db which I want to dump.

I use the command:

```
$ python manage.py dumpdata >  dump.json
```

But I get the following error:

> CommandError: Unable to serialize database: Could not decode to UTF-8
>   column 'sm s_data' with text '[{"body": "Amarnath Dutta  70229989899",
>   "date": "Thu Feb 16 18:08:52 GMT+05:30 2017", "direction": "SENT",
>   "address": "9845370953"}, {"body":  "

How can I dump the data?

Answer (score -4):

You could select only the table you need, skiiping the tables are not serialazable.
For example:

```
$ python manage.py dumpdata myapp_label.myModelName > myModelName.json
```